# CAN socketCAN - how reliable is for file transfer

Tags: linux, qt, can-bus, esp32

I want to send files (mp3 about 4MB each) to devices connected via CAN. I'm testing with Linux machine and ESP32. The problem is that not all data arrives to destination.

I'm sending from Linux machine using socketCAN and UCCB USB-CAN converter
https://www.tindie.com/products/lll7/can-usb-converter-uccb/ to ESP32, or between two ESP32.

When sending from PC Linux to ESP32, sometimes only 1/3 of mp3 file is saved, during sending I have candump slcan0 command running and it looks like all data is on the bus, but ESP32 does not see some frames.

When I send between two ESP32, for instance 4MB of data, receiving ESP32 gets around 3,98MB of data, some frames gets lost.

I'm using command "slcand -o -c -f -s8 /dev/ttyACM0 slcan0" to create slcan0 interface, although changing the speed with -s switch does not seem to work.

Am I missing something, or CAN is not suitable for such high speed, high load operations? I want to have 30 devices on canbus that receive around 1GB of data (mp3 files)

code below:

```
CanMgr::CanMgr(QObject *parent,LogModel *logModel):QObject(parent) {
    this->logModel=logModel;

    send_timer=new QTimer(this);
    send_timer->setSingleShot(true);
    send_timer->setInterval(1);
    connect(send_timer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&CanMgr::processQueue);
}
void CanMgr::connectDevice() {
    QString errorString;
    m_canDevice = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(m_pluginName,m_socketName,&errorString);

    if (!m_canDevice) {
        qDebug()<<QString("Error creating device '%1', reason: '%2'").arg(m_pluginName).arg(errorString);
        return;
    }

    m_numberFramesWritten = 0;

    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::errorOccurred, this, &CanMgr::processErrors);
    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, this, &CanMgr::processReceivedFrames);
    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::framesWritten, this, &CanMgr::processFramesWritten);
    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::stateChanged,this, &CanMgr::stateChanged);


    m_canDevice->setConfigurationParameter(QCanBusDevice::BitRateKey,"250000");
    if (!m_canDevice->connectDevice()) {
        qDebug()<<tr("Connection error: %1").arg(m_canDevice->errorString());

        delete m_canDevice;
        m_canDevice = nullptr;
    } else {

        QVariant bitRate = m_canDevice->configurationParameter(QCanBusDevice::BitRateKey);
        if (bitRate.isValid()) {
            qDebug()<<tr("Plugin: %1, connected to %2 at %3 kBit/s").arg(m_pluginName).arg(m_socketName).arg(bitRate.toInt() / 1000);
        } else {
            qDebug()<<tr("Plugin: %1, connected to %2").arg(m_pluginName).arg(m_socketName);
        }
    }
}
void CanMgr::sendFileContent(QByteArray data) {
    quint32 frameId = 0;
    quint32 dev_id=2;
    quint32 cmd_id=0;
    frameId=(dev_id<<16) | cmd_id;

    m_canDevice->clear();


    QByteArray size=Helper::byteArrFromInt((quint32)data.size(),8);
    qDebug()<<"CanMgr::sendFileContent file size in bytes:"<<Helper::printHex(size);

    QCanBusFrame frame = QCanBusFrame(frameId,size);
    frame.setExtendedFrameFormat(true);
    qDebug()<<"frame data:"<<frame.toString()<<" stat:"<<m_canDevice->state();
    queue.append(frame);

    frameId = 0;
    dev_id=2;
    cmd_id=1;

    frameId=(dev_id<<16) | cmd_id;

    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i+=8) {

        QCanBusFrame frame = QCanBusFrame(frameId, data.mid(i,8));
        frame.setExtendedFrameFormat(true);
        queue.append(frame);
    }

    frameId = 0;
    dev_id=2;
    cmd_id=2;
    frameId=(dev_id<<16) | cmd_id;


    frame = QCanBusFrame(frameId, size);
    frame.setExtendedFrameFormat(true);
    queue.append(frame);

    process_frame=false;
    send_timer->start();
}
void CanMgr::processQueue() {
    if(queue.isEmpty()) {
        qDebug()<<"CanMgr::processQueu queue empty";
        return;
    }
    if(process_frame) {
        ;
    }
    else {
        curr_frame=queue.dequeue();
        process_frame=true;
    }
    qDebug()<<"CanMgr::processQueue frame data:"<<curr_frame.toString()<<" towrite:"<<m_canDevice->framesToWrite()<<" left:"<<queue.count();

    m_canDevice->writeFrame(curr_frame);
}
void CanMgr::processFramesWritten(qint64 count) {
    qDebug()<<"CanMgr::processFramesWritten count:"<<count;
    process_frame=false;
    this->processQueue();
}
QString CanMgr::processErrors(QCanBusDevice::CanBusError error) const
{
    QString err_str;
    switch (error) {
    case QCanBusDevice::ReadError:
    case QCanBusDevice::WriteError:
    case QCanBusDevice::ConnectionError:
    case QCanBusDevice::ConfigurationError:
    case QCanBusDevice::UnknownError:
        err_str= m_canDevice->errorString();
        qDebug()<<"Error:"<<err_str;
        send_timer->start();
        return err_str;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Best,

Marek

Comment: I'd say show your I/O code.

Comment: code added to original post

Comment: You are definitely missing something because CAN does not have packet loss. Packets are only lost inside the nodes upon tx or rx buffer overruns. Either because the transmitter doesn't wait for an available buffer, or because the receiver isn't done processing all the incoming packets before the next one arrives.

Comment: @Lundin you are right. EG when I'm sending data from ESP to PC I got all the packages (surely PC is faster). When I send from PC to ESP 1/4 of packets is received on ESP, so I agree buffer overruns. But how to cope with that other than: send one packet (PC to ESP) - wait for confirmation (ESP to PC) - send another packet (PC to ESP)

Comment: Anything new about that?